# Kotlin Bundle.putString not explicitly adding "String" but instead is "String?"

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, bundle

```
val args = Bundle()
args.putString("type", details.type)

navigator.navigate(context!!, findNavController(), Destination.TYPE, args)
```

I am quite confused as to why in the receiving fragment when I go to access the arguments I have passed through it is responding with...

```
val type: String = arguments.getString("type")
```

The arguments.getString is all underlined red and says "Required String Found String?" But how when I called method "putString"?!?

It is resulting in text not being rendered in the new fragment and I assume this is a nullability issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's a matter of knowledge that is available in the receiving `Fragment`.**

The `Fragment` is not aware of how its `arguments` were created (or modified) so it has to assume the `"type"` key you're looking for might not be in the arguments `Bundle`. That's why it returns a `nullable` (`String?`) result (the `null` value would mean *absent* in arguments).

Your fragment might be created in many places in your app and its arguments might have been modified in many places. We have no way of tracking that.

---

There are different solutions for this problem, depending on your approach in other parts of the code and how "confident" you are in creating of your `Fragment`.

I would usually choose a solution in which I assume setting the `type` is **mandatory**. Therefore if the `type` is absent - I fail fast. That would mean the `Fragment` was misused.

```kotlin
val type: String = arguments!!.getString("type")!!
```

The code above will crash if either:

a) `arguments` weren't set, or

b) `String` with `type` wasn't put in the `arguments` `Bundle`.

Comment: thank you! that seems a good way of looking at fragments in general. Fail fast. I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that is a : null ability issue.

First you should be sure if you are expecting a value, so try adding "?" or "!!", i would recommend "?", or go with the block of if {} else

Comment: thanks for your help.
When I have `arguments?.getString("type")` it runs but mentions inferred type was String? when expected String. If I try to Log what comes back on the new fragment it crashes.

Comment: also adding `arguments!!.getString` crashes the app also... Confusing as the inferred type is correct - and then seems weird that it would only infer the type when putString was used

Comment: The compiler doesn't know if you used `putString` or not. Besides, your Fragment could be created somewhere else with different or no arguments. Point is: the `getString` function returns `String?`, so you have to handle the case where it returns null. It doesn't go into the 'logic' of these calls, it just sees the single function.

Comment: @Tony, try handling the case as I mentioned before. Also would suggest to try once adding : details.type.toString()

Answer (score 0):

To read the string safely you can use:

```
val type: String = arguments?.getString("type").orEmpty()
```

The orEmpty call at the end ensures that a valid String is returned even if either `arguments` or `getString()` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for `getString()` returns a nullable String. This is because at compile time, the compiler can't know if the value exists in the bundle or not. You will have the same issue when retrieving anything from any Map.

If you know for certain that the value in the bundle or map should exist at the time you call `getString()`, you can use the `!!` operator. That's what it's there for. When you *know* something should always be there, it is appropriate to want an exception to be thrown (in this case KNPE) if it's not there so you can easily find any programming error during testing.

`isEmpty()`  or `?.let` aren't helpful in this particular case because they would just be masking a programming error and making it harder to discover or debug.